# Wrapper command that runs program in temporary directory and deletes it after execution

Tags: files, scripting, directory, tmp

I want to write a command that:

1. takes another command as its arguments
2. does a 'cd' to a temporary folder
3. executes the command passed in the arguments
4. removes the temporary folder afterwards

Something like this:

```
run_in_temp_dir ~/bin/my_script_that_creates_lots_of_files.sh arg1 arg2
```

But it would make sense that such a command already exists.
So my question is, does such a command exist?

Edit: apparently people think this is a duplicate, but I specifically asked for the possible existence of a wrapper command. And yes I am perfectly capable of writing this script myself, I just don't want to reinvent the wheel if not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it exists among standard tools. Reasons:

It only works in very specific setting. For instance, most scripts are MEANT to run in the current directory because they reference local files. Even arg1 and arg2 could be local files. Most scripts would break or even do damage. For instance, what if the script itself does `rm ../*` and this ran in `/tmp/`?
Removing anything automatically is a terrible idea for a standard tool to do.

This is something you should definitely write by yourself for a specific use. Actually it makes sense that your script does that internally! If you really don't want a local environment, you could used `mktemp` to create a directory (possibly somewhere int /tmp), and put your intermediate files in there (better than cd-ing there, you just put the files there). Then you can also remove it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Many systems have a `mktemp` command that take a `-d` option, so you can simply do:

```
dir=$(mktemp -d) &&
  (cd -P -- "$dir" &&
  ~/bin/my_script_that_creates_lots_of_files.sh arg1 arg2) &&
  rm -rf -- "$dir"
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, no, such a command does not exist (at least: a portable command that does what you want).

It would be rather trivial to implement this though something resembling:

```
t_dir="$(mktemp -d)"
if [ $? -ne 0 ] || [ -z "${t_dir}" ] ; then
  printf "Unable to create temporary directory. Exiting."
  exit 1
else
  trap_tdir="rm -rf \"$t_dir\""
  trap "${trap_tdir}" 0
fi
(cd "${t_dir}" && run_your_script_with_args)
```

This snippet (untested though) should create you a temporary directory, and set it up for removel once your script finishes (that what the trap does).

We run the cd and the command inside a subshell, which means that when the subshell exits, you should be back where you started, the script will exit and the trap kicks in to clean up.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is such a command but writing it is trivial:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## create the temp directory
dir=$(mktemp -d)

## save the current directory
pwd="$PWD";

## move to the temp dir
cd "$dir"

## run the command given as an argument
"$@" &&

## remove the temp directory if the command exited successfully 
rm -rf "$dir"

## return to where you started from
cd "$pwd"
```

Not sure what the point of this is though, it will delete whatever created by the command you pass it before you have the chance to see it. I am guessing that the command you want to run will make changes elsewhere in the system, else there really isn't much point to it.